# Print regular expression non-matches only

Tags: regex, python-3.x

I'm trying to remove specific URLs that match a list of sources to exclude from the list of news articles.  I only want to print the URLs that do not match my regular expression.  I also only want to print the items in the list news_articles once.

- How do I print only the URLs that do not match?
- How do I print the non-matching URLs only once?

  ```
  import re

  sources_to_exclude = ['cnn.com','france24.com','reuters.com']

  news_articles = ['http://www.chicagotribune.com/news/nationworld/ct-south-africa-trump-tweet-20180823-story.html',
           'https://www.theatlantic.com/international/archive/2018/08/trump-rule-of-law-south-africa-farmers/568390',
           'https://www.aljazeera.com/news/2018/08/south-africa-calls-trump-misinformed-land-policy-180823060142595.html',
           'https://www.timeslive.co.za/politics/2018-08-23-trumps-administration-to-monitor-land-expropriation-in-south-africa',
           'https://mg.co.za/article/2018-08-23-south-african-politicians-resist-trumps-falsehoods-about-south-africa',
           'https://www.cnn.com/2018/08/22/africa/south-africa-racist-rant-video/index.html',
           'https://www.reuters.com/article/us-safrica-usa-presidency/south-africa-to-seek-clarification-from-us-embassy-on-trumps-land-reform-tweet-sabc-idUSKCN1L80JI',
           'https://www.thedailybeast.com/trump-bemoans-persecuted-white-farmers-in-south-africa',
           'https://www.france24.com/en/20180823-south-africa-recall-mostert-second-argentina-test']

  for result in news_articles:
    for link in sources_to_exclude:
      regex = '((http[s]?|ftp):\/)?\/?([^:\/\s]+)?({})\/([^\/]+)'.format(link)
      match = re.search(r'{}'.format(regex), result, re.IGNORECASE)
      if match:
        print ('Matched regex:  {}'.format(result))
      else:
        # I only want to print items that DID NOT match the regex pattern
        # I also want to print these items once.
        print('Did not matched regex:  {}'.format(result))
  ```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your code is almost complete. This should work:

```
for result in news_articles:
    for link in sources_to_exclude:
        regex = '((http[s]?|ftp):\/)?\/?([^:\/\s]+)?({})\/([^\/]+)'.format(link)
        match = re.search(r'{}'.format(regex), result, re.IGNORECASE)
        if match is not None:
            break
    else:
        print('Did not match any regex: {}'.format(result))
```

Python supports `else` on `for` loops. The else block is executed, if the loop exists normally (was not stopped using `break`). As the loop breaks, if any regex matches, it is only executed (and the link printed) if no regex matches.

Answer (score 4):

You can use list comprehension:

```
[i for i in news_articles if not re.search('|'.join(sources_to_exclude),i)]

Out[610]: 
['http://www.chicagotribune.com/news/nationworld/ct-south-africa-trump-tweet-20180823-story.html',
 'https://www.theatlantic.com/international/archive/2018/08/trump-rule-of-law-south-africa-farmers/568390',
 'https://www.aljazeera.com/news/2018/08/south-africa-calls-trump-misinformed-land-policy-180823060142595.html',
 'https://www.timeslive.co.za/politics/2018-08-23-trumps-administration-to-monitor-land-expropriation-in-south-africa',
 'https://mg.co.za/article/2018-08-23-south-african-politicians-resist-trumps-falsehoods-about-south-africa',
 'https://www.thedailybeast.com/trump-bemoans-persecuted-white-farmers-in-south-africa']
```

You can also do:

```
re.sub('^.*('+'|'.join(sources_to_exclude)+').*$', "", "\n".join(news_articles),flags=re.M).split()
Out[612]: 
['http://www.chicagotribune.com/news/nationworld/ct-south-africa-trump-tweet-20180823-story.html',
 'https://www.theatlantic.com/international/archive/2018/08/trump-rule-of-law-south-africa-farmers/568390',
 'https://www.aljazeera.com/news/2018/08/south-africa-calls-trump-misinformed-land-policy-180823060142595.html',
 'https://www.timeslive.co.za/politics/2018-08-23-trumps-administration-to-monitor-land-expropriation-in-south-africa',
 'https://mg.co.za/article/2018-08-23-south-african-politicians-resist-trumps-falsehoods-about-south-africa',
 'https://www.thedailybeast.com/trump-bemoans-persecuted-white-farmers-in-south-africa']
```